# How to connect to MS SQL database in Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I connect to a SQL Server 2008 database in Java with JDBC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451892/how-do-i-connect-to-a-sql-server-2008-database-in-java-with-jdbc)

I have a program that needs to connect to a MS SQL database.  But its not connecting.

Here is my code:

```
DB db = new DB();
db.dbConnect("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://WEBAPRTestSPXAMRProdSQL.Traxtech.com/WEBAPRTest_SPXAMRProd","ralph.caballes","*****");          //<-- i think the error is here

class DB
{
    public void dbConnect(String db_connect_string, String db_userid, String db_password){
            Connection con = null;

        try
        {

            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");          
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Do you get any exception/error? There are lots of examples foe connecting to mysql in java on internet. Search for it; I'm sure you will find something useful. Also why this question is tagged with `asp.net-mbvc-2` ?

Answer (score 3):

Your JDBC URL mentions [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/), which is an open source JDBC driver that *can* connect to a MS SQL Database.

But you `Class.forName` tries to load the JDBC-ODBC bridge, which is an entirely unrelated driver.

Answer (score 1):

If java

You have used wrong connection URL also the driver. see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j.html)