# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I keep on getting this error. I tried one solution from Stack Overflow (below), which did not work for me:
[SQL Exception while connecting to SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035291/ql-exception-while-connecting-to-sql-server)

I tried allowing port 1433 in the Windows firewall by using a link, that did not work either. Refer to section "To open a port in the Windows firewall for TCP access"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP
> connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error:
> "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties.  Make
> sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host  and
> accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP
> connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: What are your connection settings? Are you trying to connect to the default instance or a named instance?

Comment: @Neil - I just read about "default" and "named" instance. I typed a command and got a name. Is that the name for my instance ?
    select @@servername
    go 
The name is JUSTIN\SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: Does your code look like `con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://justin\\sqlexpress", "user", "pass");` ?

Comment: Returning after a long time. Don't even remember if i fixed this issue.

Comment: @sweet dreams-- how did you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: For me, adding port 1433 in firewall (as described in question) solved my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 57):

You need to go to
`Start > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager`

When it opens, go to `SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLExpress`.

There you'll find the Protocol TCP/IP, if disabled then Enable it. Click on TCP/IP, you'll find its properties.

In these properties, remove all the TCP Dynamic Ports and add value of 1433 to all TCP ports, and restart your `SQL Server Services > SQL Server`

And it's done.

---

EDIT:
For those who want to enable it but do not see any options in the `SQL Server Network Configuration` tab (could be because running SQL Server on Parallels Desktop on Mac M1 / M2 / M3), follow the below steps to enable it using the Windows registry.

1. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp` and make `Enabled` as 1 (decimal).
2. Expand `Tcp` and go to all the IP from 1 to All and remove the value of `TcpDynamicPorts` and set `1433` to `TcpPort`.

Comment: Still I have problem...Here is my Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852987/error-code-503-com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverexception-the-tcp-ip-connec

Comment: Is there a way to determine the current dynamic port and use it, rather than forcing it to use a static port?

Comment: Or find the port at registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp

Comment: @parth what if I dont want to enable the TCP/IP manually? How to resolve this issue without manual interaction?

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the same issue. I have tried your solution but it is not working.

Answer (score 18):

**Steps**

- Open the Sql Server Configuration Manager (Start -> Programs ->
  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 -> Configuration Tools)
- Expand SQL Server Network Configuration -> [Your Server Instance]
- Double click TCP/IP
- Under Protocol:
- Ensure Enabled is Yes
- Under IP Addresses:
- Scroll to the bottom and set the TCP Port under IPAll, (1433 by
  default)
- Find the IP address you want to connect to and set Enabled and Active
  to Yes

Answer (score 3):

To query database SQL Server with JDBC

Firstly, You need to find out the IP of your SQL Server and **Enable** TCP/IP and set TCP/IP port either. To do that, do these steps:

- **Open SQL Server Configuration Manager**

  - Choose **SQL Server Network Configuration** -> **Protocols for**  -> Right click on **TCP/IP** -> select **Enable** (if already enabled then move to next step) -> Right click to **TCP/IP** again -> **Properties** -> Choose tab **IP Address** -> In **IPAll** group: Clear value of **TCP Dynamic Ports** and set 1433 to **TCP Port**
    -> Click **OK**

    **Note:** Copy one of the IPs in the Properties table to do config later
  - Double click to **SQL Server Services** - > Right click to **SQL Server *(USER)* ** -> Choose **Restart**

Now, you already have the IP, config server as below:

```xml
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://put.the.ip.here:1433;databaseName=<DB-Name>" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="p@ssW0rd" />
</bean>
```

**Note**: Remove `destroy-method="close"` out of the bean

Answer (score 0):

be sure tha in connectionUrl, your slash is oriented to left like this:

> String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost**\**itis;databaseName=dbMediaStore;user=;password=";

Comment: Shouldn't that backslash be doubled up to escape it?