# Error code 503 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception the tcp/ip connection to host failed

Tags: iphone, sql-server-2005, jdbc, sup

Developed a SUP HWC application that will fetch data from SQL server 2005 using stored procedure.

Application deployed successfully to the server.And I'm able to view the application from my iPhone simulator.But, when I'm trying to retrieve the data on click of a menu,getting following error.

"Error code 503 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception the tcp/ip connection to host failed"

I changed my settings as per this:

[com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820799/com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverexception-the-tcp-ip-connection-to-the-ho)

But, still getting same error.Please help.Thanks.

Note: I have virtual MAC(where iPhone simulator is running) on my windows 7 PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, My problem got solved...As I was in client VPN, I got a different IP address.Now, I mapped to client VPN generated IP address and its working like a champ... :)