# The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jdbc

I'm getting this 2 errors repeatedly when I'm trying to connect eclipse with sql server through jdbc.Can anyone help me with this or explain why am GETTING THIS??

1.The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed .2.The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption.

Thank you..

this is the code am working on.

```
String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
String connString ="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/databaseName=Engg_Street;instance=SQLSERVER;encrypt=true;     trustServerCertificate=true";
String username = "Vijayalakshmi";
String password = "";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString,username,password);
```

Comment: refer to the following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820799/com-microsoft-sqlserver-jdbc-sqlserverexception-the-tcp-ip-connection-to-the-ho

Comment: Is SQL Server running on port 1433, IIRC since SQL Server 2005, TCP/IP is disabled by default and if enabled it is using a randomized port by default.

Comment: Don't post the same question multiple times, instead you should edit your existing post if you think it needs clarification!

Comment: yes, sql server is running on port 1433 and it's enabled also..

Comment: I mean the IPALL TCP PORT IS 1433, or should we assign all other to 1433..

Answer (score 0):

Take the `encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true` out of your connection string.  Your SQL Server probably isn't set up to use SSL for its connections.