# Anylogic 7.2 database object conectivity to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, anylogic

I have a problem with the Anylogic 7.2 database object connecting to SQL Server.  I am new to Anylogic, but as far as I can tell I have set it up correctly.  To set up connectivity to SQL Server, I downloaded sqljdbc4-3.0.jar and set it as a model dependency in the top level model.  In the 'imports' section of 'main', I call import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;

The user login has the relevant privileges to the database in question, and the username/password combination work.  The user can connect through SQL Server Management Studio.

In the Anylogic database connection wizard I have set host to (local), ., local, localhost, (localhost) - none appear to work.  When I try to connect to return the list of tables, the result returned is null.

I am not knowledgeable of SQL Server, but I think it is set up properly.  I am all out ideas and not sure how to resolve this one.  If anybody has a clue I would be very grateful to hear.

Thanks.

Comment: You say they can connect via Management Studio but nothing else. Questions:

1. Is the user a Sql Server user?
2. Is Sql Server set to talk via TCP?
3. Have you tried connecting via an ODBC connection via Administrative Tools menu to confirm it's not a driver issue?

Comment: Hello Rachel.  Thank you for your reply.  In answer to your questions: 1. Yes, the user is a SQL Server login account.  2.  TCP/IP is enabled.  3.  Yes, ODBC works fine with the same user credentials.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.  Rob

Comment: Can you post a fragment of code? Heaven knows I'm no coding maven but I might be able to cast a fresh pair of eyes over it - me or some other wondering soul here at SO...

Comment: Also, does any of this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930023/connect-jdbc-with-sql-server

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I will, but I am out for the evening at the moment and don't have my work machine with me.  Rob

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help Rachel.  Eventually I got to the bottom of this one.  After going through log files from Anylogic and SQL Server it became clear that Anylogic was failing to reach SQL Server, i.e. there was no attempt to login.  So, I turned off my firewall and all worked as intended.  It seemed that the firewall was blocking communication on port 1433.  I set up explicit firewall rules to allow communication over ports 1433 and 1434 and now the issue appears to be resolved.