# Connection String of MS-SQL to put in JAVA

Tags: java, database, mssql-jdbc

What should be the connection string for MSSQL Database in JAVA? Something like this.

[image]

Like someother things I want to know that Is there any password in connection string like password of my computer? what should be the port number, url etc? If you need more information about the connection let me know.

P.S. The black line has the servername.

My Connection values

```
datasource.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://MSSQLSERVERFULL;databaseName=xproctor;
datasource.user=JUNAID-VAIO\Shamim
datasource.password=
```

**ERROR:**
here is the ERROR I get while trying to connect database!!

> Error querying database.  Cause:
>   org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host
>   MSSQLSERVERFULL, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the
>   connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is
>   running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make
>   sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a
>   firewall.".)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect to a SQL Server 2008 database in Java with JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451892/how-do-i-connect-to-a-sql-server-2008-database-in-java-with-jdbc)

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne is there any password involve? like of my computer password or something like this?

Comment: if you didn't put  a password for sql server put it as blank

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne Question updated. Please check.

Comment: Since you are using SQL Server 2012 you can do http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342342(v=sql.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use this connection string:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://;servername=server_name;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos
```

Answer (score 0):

The TCP/IP connection to the host has failed. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect". 
Enable Name pipes, TCP/IP, change Authentication mode, change localhost to 127.0.0.1 or ., 
add the Instance Name to the url, change the port, enable port and Apps in the firewall... almost everything. 
Its horrible! But the answer for your problem is: **open SQL Server Configuration Manager -> Protocols for SQL SQLEXPRESS, select Properties of TCP/IP. In the tab IP Addresses, set the TCPPort in section IPAll to 1433.**