# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Hello i need to connect my java program to a Microsoft Sql server. I get 
`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://LB236:1521;databasename=checkpointDB` 
I cant not find any problems pleas look at my code and tell me whats wrong.

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://"+ properties.getProperty(CP.dbHost.toString())+":"+properties.getProperty(CP.dbPort.toString())+";databasename="+properties.getProperty(CP.dbDatabase.toString()),properties.getProperty(CP.dbUser.toString()),AppDecrypter.getInstance().decrypt(properties.getProperty(CP.dbPassword.toString())));
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://LB236:1521;databasename=checkpointDB
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at de.mvn.gotdb_mvn.Importer.openConnection(Importer.java:117)
at de.mvn.gotdb_mvn.Importer.openConnection(Importer.java:135)
at de.mvn.gotdb_mvn.Main.main(Main.java:33)
```

Comment: Have you put your `sqljdbc.jar` under WEB-INF/lib folder? Make sure it resides there

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451892/how-do-i-connect-to-a-sql-server-2008-database-in-java-with-jdbc

Comment: Are you sure about the JDBC URL? It looks suspicious to me

Comment: sqljdbc.jar is in my local repository and it is not a web application

Comment: @Parth What part of the question made you believe it is a web application?

Comment: try removing `microsoft:` from the JDBC url

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: Thought so as I was facing the same problem as well. That's why I made a comment. Anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection url should be like this:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://"+.......
```

Omit the ":microsoft" from the connection string.

Hope this works.

Comment: removing ":mircosoft" from and chaning to java 7 fixed it

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the JDBC url you have put.

It should be *jdbc:sqlserver://ServerName\sqlexpress.....*

Make sure that the sqljdbc jar file which you are using is included in the build path of your project.

[Here is a good tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2011/03/02/getting-started-with-the-sql-server-jdbc-driver.aspx) for sql server