# JDBC - cannot connect with a localhost

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I am trying to connect with Microsoft SQL Server Database called SimpleBase, which is on my computer with this code:

```
    static final String JDBCDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/SimpleBase";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

            Connection conn = null;
            Statement stmt = null;

            try{
                    Class.forName(JDBCDriver);
                    System.out.println("Connecting");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
                    conn.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException se){
                    se.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

and the output in Eclipse is something like this:

```
Connecting

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The  driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1038)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:338)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2270)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2069)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:389)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at PROKOM.Zadanie11.test.main(test.java:23)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:213)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:297)
... 15 more
```

I suspect that I did something wrong. Can someone tell me what?
If it's not exactly my fault, can someone tell what's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `jdbc:mysql` is correct for MS SQL Server?

Comment: @Filburt: I was going to ask that very same question myself. It doesn't seem to make sense, does it?

Comment: check: [How do I connect to a SQL Server 2008 database in Java with JDBC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451892/how-do-i-connect-to-a-sql-server-2008-database-in-java-with-jdbc)

Answer (score 2):

`MySQL` and `SQL Server` use different driver classes and connection URLs

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");    
connection = DriverManager.getConnection
("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=SimpleBase", "user", "");
```

SQL server uses a [JDBC type 4 driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) so it isnt necessary to load the JDBC driver explicitly