# How to connect to SQL Server using ODBC driver?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to open a connection to a Microsoft SQL Server, I opened the ODBC and went to the System DSN->add->selected SQL Server. However there are no SQL Servers to connect to.

This is probably a simple fix, but this is the first time I'm dealing with microsoft SQL Server

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451892/how-do-i-connect-to-a-sql-server-2008-database-in-java-with-jdbc

Because you should use JDBC instead of ODBC.

With ODBC You will have to deal with 32bit and 64bit ODBC Sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just type in the name of the SQL Server instance you want to connect to. If it's a default instance type the servername. If it's a named instance type in servername\instancename. You'll then be able to configure the DSN as needed.

The control for list of available servers is notoriously unreliable for what is actually available/reachable.